# Multidimensional array using module-array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I would like to create a 2d array of integers using array module. I know that, I can easily create a 2d array using list but I would like to explore array module since they are compact.

```
from array import array
a = array('i', [1, 2, 3, 4])  # working fine
a = array('i', [[1, 2], [3, 4]]) # throws error
```

Answer (score 2):

From: https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html

"This module defines an object type which can compactly represent an array of basic values: characters, integers, floating point numbers. Arrays are sequence types and behave very much like lists, except that the type of objects stored in them is constrained."

Basically, it seems that you cannot store lists inside.
I would recommend other modules like numpy for 2+dimensional matrices.